# Extension PHP with C. Creating the first environment I got awk syntax error using ext_skel

Tags: php, awk

Extension PHP with C. Creating the first environment I got awk syntax error using ext_skel

The error's above:

```
enter code here
awk: syntax error at source line 256 source file /Users/Princelo/Downloads/php-5.5.14/ext/skeleton/create_stubs
 context is
                         if (!stubs) print "" > extname >>>  "/function_warning" <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 257 source file /Users/Princelo/Downloads/php-5.5.14/ext/skeleton/create_stubs
awk: syntax error at source line 267 source file /Users/Princelo/Downloads/php-5.5.14/ext/skeleton/create_stubs
rm: function_entries: No such file or directory
rm: function_declarations: No such file or directory
rm: function_stubs: No such file or directory
enter code here
```

It generated myextension.c which doesn't have the function "PHP_FUNCTION(myextension)".
How to fix the problem? My OS is Yosemite, PHP version 5.5.14. Thanks!

the source of create_stubs from line 251 to end:

```
    enter code here
        print proto > stubfile
        if (funcvals) print funcvals > stubfile
        if (fetchargs) print fetchargs > stubfile
        if (resources) {
                print resources > stubfile
                if (!stubs) print "" > extname "/function_warning"
        }
        if (!i_know_what_to_do_shut_up_i_dont_need_your_help_mode) {
            print "\tphp_error(E_WARNING, \"" funcs[i] ": not yet implemented\");" > stubfile
        }
        print "}\n/* }}} */\n" > stubfile

        if (stubs) {
            h_stubs = h_stubs "PHP_FUNCTION(" funcs[i] ");\n"
            c_stubs = c_stubs "\tPHP_FE(" funcs[i] ",\tNULL)\n"
        } else {
            print "PHP_FUNCTION(" funcs[i] ");" > extname "/function_declarations"
            print "\tPHP_FE(" funcs[i] ",\tNULL)" > extname "/function_entries"
        }

        if (xml) print xmlstr > xmldoc
    }

    if (stubs) {
        print "\n/* ----------------------------------------------------------- */\n" > stubfile
        print c_stubs > stubfile
        print "\n/* ----------------------------------------------------------- */\n" > stubfile
        print h_stubs > stubfile
    }

    if (xml) print xmlfoot > xmldoc
}

#
# Local variables:
# tab-width: 2
# c-basic-offset: 2
# End:

enter code here
```

Comment: The error message says you have a syntax error at line 256 of your awk script. How could we possibly help you debug that without at the very least you posting line 256 with a few lines of context around it? It says you have a syntax error on line 267 as well so I recommend you edit your question to show lines 250-270 of your script, with line numbers at the front (use `cat -n` if on UNIX) so we know which lines of the script the error messages above are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 256 is

```
if (!stubs) print "" > extname "/function_warning"
```

Expressions on the right side of a `>` must be parenthesized:

```
if (!stubs) print "" > ( extname "/function_warning" )
```

as the order of evaluation is implementation dependent. Ditto for your other print lines.